# google address autocomplete doesn't input suburb

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using google address autocomplete plugin for Woocommerce and it works fine except it's not inputting the correct part of the address into the city field.

For example, if I use the address 1 Marine Circle, Table View, Cape Town.. it comes up fine but then 'Table View' disappears, so my fields are populated as follows -

Address 1 - 1 Marine Circle

City - Cape Town

Province - Western Cape

How do i add a field for suburb and get 'Table View' to be populated into this field.  Or if I can't add a field, how do i populate this into the "City" field, rather than Cape Town. It's confusing people because their suburb isn't populated in the shipping fields.

Ideally, I want to see the following -

Address 1 - 1 Marine Circle

Suburb - Table View

City - Cape Town

Province - Western Cape

It currently looks like the below image, thanks!

[image: current screenshot]

Comment: You should better ask plugin authors, as this seems like a bug in the plugin.

Comment: Okay thanks.. i've emailed them so i'm just waiting for a response. I will post it here for others' information when I get it

Comment: @Michelle This is still happening - and it's now 2022!  I have exactly the same issue, using the ELExtensions plugin.  Did you ever find a way to fix it?

Comment: No I never did get this fixed sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar issue with this plugin. TownCity field would not autocomplete for UK addresses but all other fields would complete correctly. Addresses outside of the UK seemed to work as expected.

I didnt get much luck with support but someone else I know did. The resolution as of March 2023 plugin version 1.0.6 was to turn off the field mapping. Without field mapping enabled, all fields auto completed as expected.

The documentation is very short and doesnt cover field mapping etc and this solution was counter intuitive. Hopefully it will work for anyone that comes here with the same issue.

Kind regards
Paul